# Opus Codec Android Convert stream

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, opus

I'm using https://github.com/louisyonge/opus_android  to record and play opus audio.

What I really wanted is, convert the input audio buffer to opus stream for sending to the server.

```
opusTool.writeFrame(ByteBuffer frame, int len);
```

will write the encoded frame to file. Instead of writing to file, I would like to get the encoded data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Joseph

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm no expert I think you can use:

```
/**
 * Reading from opus file
 *
 * @param buffer
 * @param capacity
 */
public native void readOpusFile(ByteBuffer buffer, int capacity);
```